# QPixmap How to compare if two pixmap(pictures) are same or different

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qpixmap

Hi i have this QUI project its based match 3 game. I have problem with checking if in row there is 3 same type pic. i try to check if the next label in row is same picture and add it to new vector adding at the moment i cant find any way i could compare two pictures. I have tried chacheKey and few other methods but don't make them work. If they are same i could use any help to this project. Thank you.

```
QPixmap pic_value = labels[y][x]->pixmap(Qt::ReturnByValue);
QPixmap pic_value2 = labels[y][x+1]->pixmap(Qt::ReturnByValue);

if (pic_value.cacheKey() == pic_value2.cacheKey())
{
 match_set.append(labels[y][x+1]);
}
```

Comment: Would be perhaps easier, if you didn't compare images, but instead used some other data, like enums or integers to compare the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
if (pic_value.toImage() == pic_value2.toImage())
```

Reference: https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/13537-do-we-can-t-compare-QIcon-or-QPixmap

Answer (score 0):

First, unfortunately you can't compare QPixmap directly with the == operator so you will compare it by transferring it to an image then compare it.

```
if (mLogo.toImage() == logo.toImage())
      return;
```

Secondaly, based on the QImage comparison from this [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#operator-eq-eq)

> The comparison can be slow, unless there is some obvious difference (e.g. different size or format), in which case the function will return quickly.

So, the operation of setting the mLogo to logo is easier than the checking for comparison.